# MySQL ReadOnly user cannot see slow query log

Tags: mysql, user-management

I have the MySQL slow query log turned on.  For my main user account I can run this query and see results:

```
select * from mysql.slow_log limit 1;
```

I also have a "readonly" user account.  This account has SELECT permission for every schema.  When I log in as this user and run the above query, I get 0 results.  No error or warning appears, it just looks like the log is empty.

Do I need to give my "readonly" user another permission or something?  Any ideas?